# On Richard Guy's problem D5 in "Unsolved problems in Number Theory"

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

This question is motivated by recent discovery of [Andrew Booker+Andrew Sutherland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sums_of_three_cubes).

Richard Guy's problem D5 in his [Unsolved Problems in Number Theory](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387208602) contains the original question for the sum of three cubes and a few other interesting problems, e.g. the solutions of Diophantine equation $$x^3+y^3+2z^3=k,$$ where $k$ is an integer neither a cube nor twice a cube. For $k<1000$, only two candidates $k=148, 671$ are left(see Tomita Seiji's [database](http://www.maroon.dti.ne.jp/fermat/fourcubes1.html)).

**Question:** Is there any known computational effort for these two Diophantine equations?

Answer (score 1):

Above equation shown below:

```
           $x^3+y^3+2z^3=K$ -----$(1)$
```

Allan Macleod has given a method for finding

numerical solutions to equation $(1)$.

The link to his article is given below.

```
    https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.2396.pdf
```

If "OP" has done some research on equation $(1)$ then

maybe he can post it on "math overflow" website.

That way it may help others to find more numerical

solutions to the unknown values of $'K'$ in equation $(1)$.